# Github URL not copied from original profile after joining a new SE site

Tags: bug, profile-page, user-accounts, github

I have set a Github URL on Stack Overflow (my oldest SE profile).

After joining a new site in the Stack Exchange network (Vi), I noticed that most of my profile was copied, except for the link to my Github profile.

Comment: It appears to still be the case in 2020